# How to use a local image as a button icon in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am new at react js. Currently getting trouble while trying to use a local image as default icon for a button. But getting no luck.

```
var NavigationBar = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
        <aside style={{float:"left",background:"#9999FF", height:"200px"}} class="navclass">
        <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Templates</a>

                      <ul> 
                       //<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <button><a href="#"><Image source={require('./template1.png')} style={{width:"28px", height:"28px"}}></Image>Template1</a></button>
                        <button><a href="#"><Image source={require('./template2.png')} style={{width:"28px", height:"28px"}}></Image>Template2</a></button>
                       //</form>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Figures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Background Color</a></li>
                    <ImageUpload/>
           </ul>
          </aside>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what are you talking about, `React` or `React-Native` ?

`<Image />` is definetly a react-native component, and as I see from syntax you have copied this piece of code from some react-native example or tutorial, and all other tags are html... Maybe you should better try to use simple `<img src='...' />`. It should work.